# In IIS, how can I forward all my URLs to a non-www, https, and no file extension without having too many redirects

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, file-extension, no-www

I have gone through many similar questions in Stack Overflow, but I have not been able to find one that helps me to have all three of these re-direct rules work together.

I am trying to forward all of my URLs to this format:

```
https://example.com/page
```

I need the https, I don't want the www, and I don't want the html or aspx extensions to be visible. Here is what I have so far. Chrome says that I have too many redirects, how do I consolidate these rules?

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />

            <rule name="RewriteHTML">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="Redirect www to non-www" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)\.html$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>

            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)\.html$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>

            <rule name="RemoveExtension" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="(.*)\.html$" />
                 <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after playing around with patterns and rule orders, and the stopProcessing command, etc. No more redirect loops! I actually figured out what I was asking and more.

1. Removes index.html from root domain
2. Redirects www to non-www
3. Removes trailing slashes
4. Makes the URL always lowercase
5. Redirects http:// to https://
6. Enables URL to work without .html extension
7. Redirects to URL without .html extension

My code:

```
<rules>         
    <!-- index.html Redirect -->    
    <rule name="index.html Redirect" enabled="true">
        <match url="^(.*\/)*index\.html$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" negate="true" pattern="^POST$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule> 

    <!-- Redirect WWW to non-WWW -->
    <rule name="Redirect WWW to non-WWW" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Remove Trailing Slash -->
    <rule name="Remove Trailing Slash" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)/$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Make URL Lower Case -->
    <rule name="Make URL Lower Case" enabled="true">
        <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Redirect To HTTPS -->
    <rule name="Redirect To HTTPS" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Redirect To URL With No Extension -->
    <rule name="Redirect To URL With No Extension" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)\.(html)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>             

    <!-- Rewrite URL For No Extension -->
    <rule name="Rewrite URL For No Extension" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
    </rule> 
</rules>
```

Here is what the rules look like in the IIS URL Rewrite module:

[image: URL Rewrite Rule Details]